# Open Visual Studio Code from the Command Line in Windows

Tags: visual-studio-code

How open Visual Studio Code from the command line prompt?

For example:

> sublime .

This opens Sublime Text with the current path from the Command Line.
Is this also possible With Visual Studio Code?

Comment: try `cd` to your directory and then `code .`

Comment: Great @Louis, I tried many options but not this one, Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cd` to your directory and then `code .`

Comment: Better to launch code.cmd (instead of just "code", which launches code.exe).  see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56134836/visual-studio-code-launched-from-command-line-conflates-the-two-processes/56134837#56134837

Answer (score 1):

```
Users\"yourUser"\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Visual Studio Code>code .
```

So basicly: `code .`

In my case this works just fine. Going to the directory where VSCode is installed, then opening it by the name of the app.

There is not even need to go to the path. Open console "cmd" and type `code .`

```
C:\Users\USER>code .
```